# Delphi - Generics type constraint ordinal types

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe7

I want to bound type T for both types Integer and string:

```
interface

type
  MyFactory<T> = class
  public
    function createGenerator<T:Integer,string>:IGenerator<T>;
  end;
```

But the compiler gives: '(..) E2510 Type 'Integer' is not a valid constraint'. How can I restrict type T to be a Integer or string? Or is this a problem because I am using ordinal types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delphi generics do not support ordinal or string type constraints.

Only allowed constraints are

- Zero, one, or multiple interface types
- Zero or one class type
- The reserved word "constructor", "class", or "record"

[Delphi Constraints in Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics)

I can only guess what exactly you are trying to accomplish but following code may give you some ideas

```
  IGenerator<T> = interface
    function Generate: T;
  end;

  TStringGenerator = class(TInterfacedObject, IGenerator<string>)
  public
    function Generate: string;
  end;

  TIntegerGenerator = class(TInterfacedObject, IGenerator<integer>)
  public
    function Generate: integer;
  end;

  MyFactory<T> = class
  public
    class function createGenerator<T>: IGenerator<T>;
  end;

class function MyFactory<T>.createGenerator<T>: IGenerator<T>;
var
  gs: IGenerator<string>;
  gi: IGenerator<integer>;
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(string) then
    begin
      gs := TStringGenerator.Create;
      Result := IGenerator<T>(gs);
    end
  else
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(integer) then
    begin
      gi := TIntegerGenerator.Create;
      Result := IGenerator<T>(gi);
    end
  else Result := nil;
end;

function TIntegerGenerator.Generate: integer;
begin
  Result := 10;
end;

function TStringGenerator.Generate: string;
begin
  Result := 'abc';
end;

var
  i: integer;
  s: string;

  i := MyFactory<integer>.createGenerator<integer>.generate;
  s := MyFactory<string>.createGenerator<string>.generate;
```

[TTypeKind](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TypInfo.TTypeKind) can also be used instead of `TypeInfo` for determining type. Main difference is that `TypeInfo` gives you exact type used, while `TTypeKind` covers all types that fall into certain category. While `TTypeKind` gives more flexibility, it should be used with caution if code depends on typecasts. For instance `tkInteger` covers both `integer` and `byte` types, and typecast can cause errors.

```
class function MyFactory<T>.createGenerator<T>: IGenerator<T>;
var
  gs: IGenerator<string>;
  gi: IGenerator<integer>;
begin
  case PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T)).Kind of
    tkUString :
      begin
        gs := TStringGenerator.Create;
        Result := IGenerator<T>(gs);
      end;
    tkInteger :
      begin
        gi := TIntegerGenerator.Create;
        Result := IGenerator<T>(gi);
      end
    else Result := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @TLama That would be good. That would let the reader know that the answer has now been surpassed by the language. If we link to a specific version (and I edited because the original linked to XE6 rather than the current version which is XE7) then future readers miss the opportunity to discover such developments.

Comment: `GetTypeKind` would be more appropriate here I think.

Comment: @David depends on code. `TypeInfo` gives exact type and that is important for typecasting in my example.

Comment: Maybe. I took ordinal to mean, well ordinal. But perhaps it means `integer`.

Comment: Please don't call it 2-4 times, even if it doesn't have much overhead. You can use `PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T)).Kind` in a case or assign it to a local variable of `TTypeKind`.

Comment: You really should do a case on the TTypeKind instead of a direct compare of the TypeInfo. The code will fail for something like `MyString = type string`.